# Is it possible to restrict access by ip

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I've spent the day searching for a way to restrict the google cloud storage json API to only accept calls from our server ip (note, I am using the java client).

I found a really old post that seemed to indicate that it was possible. https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!searchin/gs-discussion/Whitelist$20/gs-discussion/nTwMuygttbA

But things seem to have changed since then.

I tried looking in the quota section in the console but can't find anything there either.

Is this possible? Where can it be configured?